# Set a DIV height equal with of another DIV height

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have two DIVs, `.prev` and `.SLDR-ONE` and I want to set `.prev` to keep the same height with `.SLDR-ONE`.

I've tried the following:

```
$(".prev").css({'height':($(".SLDR-ONE").height()+'px')});
```

It is not working properly because `.SLDR-ONE` doesn't have defined height. `.prev` take the height of the page except if I define a height to `.SLDR-ONE` (ex:300px).

`.SLDR-ONE` has css : `float:left; position:relative`, so the height is defined automaticaly.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect

Comment: can you try this? `https://jsbin.com/roviwi`

Comment: @plonkminbuzz I tried and I don't know why but my height is not really equal. there is 20-30px of difference...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use innerHeight, to obtain the height of .prev.

Answer (score 1):

You could do this using [offsetHeight](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/offsetHeight)

```js
(function(){
var one = document.querySelector('.one');
var two = document.querySelector('.two')
two.style.height = one.offsetHeight + 'px'; 
}())
```

```css
.one{
 float: left;
 position: relative;
}
.two{
 background: #ccc;
 clear: both;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="one">
 <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing </p>
</div>
<div class="two">
 
</div> 
</body>
</html>
```

If you prefer jQuery then you could use `innerHeight`. [innerHeight](http://api.jquery.com/innerheight/) documentation.

Answer (score 0):

As from .height() method of jQuery returns width of the element excluding padding ,margin and bottom.So if you want same height for both of the div

1. You should be using outerHeight().
   And there are possibility that you have assigned the same class to some other element and the method may be returning value of width and height of that element.